# Upload a picture to database with laravel

Tags: database, laravel, image, upload

i ve created a database in localhost and table in it called gallery. I want to upload and store pictures there but i m stuck.. Can you please give me any guides or tutorial how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You need to add some code of what you have done so far

Comment: You must show the code you've written, also there are a lot of examples and videos on the internet you just need to google `how to upload photo in laravel`

Answer (score 0):

upload file just refer to [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)

for example photo is the name fo file in form

```
<form action="xxx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="photo" />
   <input type="submit" value="update" />
</form>
```

store the file then return file's path in filesystem

```
$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg');

$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg', 's3');
```

then store the $path to your database

Answer (score 0):

> First you need the form on your view (don't forget the csrf token):

```
<form action="/image-upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

> And on your routes file add the route for POST method:

```
Route::post('image-upload', 'ImageUploadController@imageUploadPost');
```

> Then on your Controller create the function that will validate and
>   move your image to the `'public/images'` folder.

```
public function imageUploadPost()
{
    request()->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
}
```